# How to Swagger annotate nested REST resources?

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

I am using swagger 1.3.0 with Jersey 1.x. I am trying to add swagger documentation for my resource methods as below:

```
@Api(.....)
class RootResource{

  @GET
  @Path("/")
  @ApiOperation(....)
  @ApiResponse(....)
  public Response get(){} // i am able to get this method's swagger doc

  @Path("/nestedResource")
  public NestedResource getNestedResource(){
    return new NestedResource();
  }     

}

class NestedResource{

  @GET
  @ApiOperation(....)
  @ApiResponse(....)
  public Response getNestedResource(){} // i am NOT able to get this method's swagger doc

}
```

Please understand the above code is just a template and NOT a complete working version.

Please let me know how to add swagger doc for Nested Resources. Thanks for the Help in Advance :)

Comment: Have you tried annotating the nested class with the same annotation as the parent class?

Comment: Yes and i got it working. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by annotating the NestedResource like below:

```
 /* Yes,i left the value attribute as blank so that path will be constructed 
 as "/NestedResource" */
@Api(basePath="/",value="") 
class NestedResource{

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(....)
    @ApiResponse(....)
    public Response getNestedResource(){}

}
```